# My app crashes once I try and make a GET request. What can I do to overcome this error?

Tags: java, android, get

I am really confused as to why I am having this problem. I have tested multiple different ways to make GET requests and they all come up with the same result. I have tested the different ways in IDEA and they all work great. I am very new to android development so I am not really sure where to start when solving this problem. I believe I have all the required permissions in the manifest file for networking so I am completely lost. Here is the code segment that makes sends the GET request.

```
    // HTTP GET request
    public String sendGet(String url_given) {

        String url = url_given;
        String final_response = "FAILED!";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);

            final_response = response.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return final_response;
    }
```

Here is the onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_for_discogs);

    RelativeLayout touch = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.touch);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView quoteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
    final TextView personText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.person);

    final SetText new_text = new SetText();

    final String url = new_text.createURL("a%20lot%20like%20birds", "conversation%20piece");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            quoteText.setText(new_text.sendURL(url));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please post error log here

Comment: post the stacktrace please.

Comment: See that's the thing. It is not printing anything into the logcat.

Comment: If it crashes, it must be generating crash report. see/post that. Are you trying to use http communication in main thread?

Comment: Yeah, you might be getting a NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

Comment: Where can I find the crash report? In the main thread it calls the method sendURL with the url string. This then sends the url to sendGet that returns the response.

Comment: The crash report can be found in the Logcat. we must need the crash report  to solve your problem.

Comment: You are not showinig where you call sendGet(). Please show/tell.

Answer (score 1):

These are some possible solutions for your problem

1- You may have forgotten to add internet permission to your AndroidManifes.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2- You probably run the connection on MainThread. for solving this problem you should use asynctask which you can read about it in links below

[AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[AsyncTasks2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: I have added the permissions in the manifest. I will read over the asybctasks. Thank you.

Comment: so you didn't add the INTERNET Permission ?

Comment: try with `AsyncTask` as the above answer...your app may crashes due to `NetworkOnMainThreadException`...